# Export data from Access to Excel2013 without activation

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, ms-office, ms-access-2013

Users can export data from my Access2013 application to Excel2013. In Access, CreateObject creates an Excel instance and via VBA methods the data are manipulated and stored in Excel in the background. (see code excerpt below)
This worked nicely in earlier Office versions, but if Excel2013 is not activated yet, the activation window pops up after a few seconds. But as the Excel object’s visibility is set to false, the activation window is hidden for the user. Then my Access application freezes because one of the VBA methods won’t return and the user will have no idea what happened or how to resolve the issue.

I’d like my application to a) either check before the export whether Excel is activated or b) when the problem arises finish properly and prompt an error message.

My failed approaches:
1) check activation status before export: call OSPP.VBS and pipe results into text file, then parse text file. Problems: OSPP.VBS requires elevated admin rights; I couldn’t find documentation on the output format and there may be various entries (runtime, trial, full …)

2)  Working with form timers and DoEvents to catch the hanging method after a timeout, but this doesn’t work.

3) Launch a second Access application which tests if the Excel problem arises, and if it does, kill the second application. Problem: the duration until the activation window pops up varies, so sometimes the second app works fine, sometimes it doesn’t.

Any hints and ideas will be appreciated!

```
Set objxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo ExcelErrorHandler
objxl.Visible = False
objxl.Workbooks.Open (strPath & TMP_FILE)
objxl.Workbooks(TMP_FILE).Worksheets(1).Name = "Report"
objxl.Workbooks(TMP_FILE).Save
objxl.Workbooks.Open (strPath & "TemplateTexts.xlsx")
objxl.Workbooks.Add (strPath & strCurrTemplate)
'***** convert formulas to 'real' values in target excel sheet strFullFileName
objxl.Cells.Select
objxl.Selection.Copy
objxl.Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
objxl.Range("A1").Select
objxl.Selection.Copy
objxl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFullFileName
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the excel application must remain hidden? In my own experience, making the excel app visible, solves this problem, since access must wait until the excel application is fully opened. Afterwards, the user has immediate access to the excel report.

Comment: I agree, the problem would be solved. However, as three workbooks are opened and data is copied and formatted, there's heavy flickering which should be avoided in default mode.

Comment: Just a guess, perhaps `objxl.DisplayAlerts = False` could solve it?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, too, but no luck.

Comment: Then, which vba method does not return, with which error and description?

Comment: That depends on how quick the activation assistant pops up. Sometimes PasteSpecial, sometimes SaveAs, sometimes Copy. As the method doesn't return, there is no error thrown; Excel just sits and waits for the user to click on the activation window's buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies to the staff if this is deemed to be in the wrong section, I don't have enough reputation to add a comment but want to reply to a comment... If screen flickering is the only thing stopping you from making the workbook visible, have you considered adding the following line?

```
objxl.screenupdating = false
```

I don't know if it will stop the Application screen from showing as it opens, but it should stop any other processes in the application from causing flickering.

Comment: The activation window still pops up, but at least the flickering stops, which is an improvement. Thanks.

Comment: This might be extremely dirty, but perhaps you could use the sendkeys method to press enter when the popup opens. Note; Extremely prone to errors and should only be used as a last resort, when everything else seems to fail

Comment: @JenZzz: My problem is that I can't find out when the activation wizard pops up. My Access VBA code just freezes; no error handler will help.

Comment: Last guess, then I'm out; have you tried putting the `objxl.displayalerts` command before setting the createobject?

Comment: Yes, I have, but it didn't have an effect on the activation window.